# SELECT DINAMICO CODEIGNITER - AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Olá!
Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

**tbl_lancamento**
**tbl_categoria**
**tbl_encargo**

Sendo que em `tbl_lacamento` existe um campo (`id_categoria`) que recebe os ids de `tbl_categoria` e `tbl_categoria` recebe o respectivo id(`id_juros`), vindo da tabela `tbl_juros`.

Estou utilizando codeigniter e pretendo exibir no em um campo `hidden` `<input type="hidden" id="juros" name="txt_juros" placeholder="juros" title="juros"/>` no view `lançamento` todas as categorias da `tbl_categoria`, e quero exibir de forma dinamica, todos os `ids_juros` relacionadas a `tbl_categoria`.

Pode me conduzir a algum código que faça isso? Acredito que isto seria trabalho para ajax, eu tentei relacionar, seguindo um exemplo de estados e cidades, mas não consegui, pois o ids relacionados estão na tabela pai.

O que tenho hoje, exibe somente as categorias.
Abaixo um código da view

```html
<select id="categoria" class="form-control" name="sel_id_categoria" >
    <?php foreach ($categoria as $categoria) {
       echo '<option value="'.$categoria->id.'">'.$categoria->descricao.'</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

Código do controller lancamento

```html
//Listar Categorias ativas Receitas e Despesas
$this->load->model('app/Categoria_model');
$this->data['categoria'] = $this->Categoria_model->obter_ativo('tbl_categoria', 'tbl_categoria.id,tbl_categoria.descricao');
```

Código no model Categoria_model

```html
 //Listar ativos
  var $tabela = 'tbl_categoria'; 
 function obter_ativo($tabela,$campos)
 {        
        $this->db->select($campos);
        $this->db->from($tabela);
        $this->db->where('situacao',1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();;
  }
```

```html
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `tbl_lancamento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_lancamento`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_lancamento`(
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `dt_lancamento` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,  
  `descricao` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `dt_vencimento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `id_categoria` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_juros` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_conta` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `baixado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `valor_pagamento` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `dt_pagamento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,  
  `forma_pagamento` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `estornado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `observacao` TEXT(160) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_tbl_lancamento_tbl_conta` (`id_conta` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_lancamento_tbl_conta`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_conta`)
  REFERENCES `tbl_conta` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
  )
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_categoria`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_categoria` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `id_juros` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `aplicar_juros` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  `situacao` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_encargo`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_encargo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `descricao` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `juros` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `multa` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `funcao` varchar(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `situacao` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: primeiro de tudo, não é bom você ficar mostrando o nome de suas tabelas assim no SO, por questões de segurança sempre altere os nomes antes de postar a pergunta. você passou o código create completo, cuidado com isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

```
<select id="categoria" class="form-control" name="sel_id_categoria" >
    <?php foreach ($categoria as $categoria) {
       echo '<option value="'.$categoria->id.'">'.$categoria->descricao.'</option>';
    } ?>
</select>

<input type="hidden" name="juros" id="juros" value="">


<script>
    $("#categoria").change(function(){
        var categoria = $("#categoria").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/buscar_juros", // Metodo de buscar juros
                type: "POST",
                data: {categoria:categoria},
                success: function(data){
                    $("#juros").val(data);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

**ajax/buscar_juros**

```
public function buscar_juros(){
    $this->db->where('categoria', $this->input->post('categoria'));
    echo $this->db->get("juros")->row('taxa_juros');
}
```

Comment: Perfeito André!
Funcionou!!!
Obrigado!